# Would like to change to each end of word instead of end of string (matching) - MariaDB/MySQL + REGEXP_REPLACE

Tags: mysql, regexp-replace

Would like to change to each end of word instead of end of string (matching)?

**I have this query now:**

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(name,"(a|o|e|y|cy|dzy|rzy|owie|i|u|ów|owi|em)$",'') FROM `zp_poster`
```

**Example query:**

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE("Józefowi Piłsudski","(a|o|e|y|cy|dzy|rzy|owie|i|u|ów|owi|em)$",'')
```

> Expected result:
>
> ```
> Józef Piłsudsk
> ```
>
> Real result:
>
> ```
> Józefowi Piłsudsk
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *word boundaries* character class.

As [explained in the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#regexp-compatibility), starting with version 8.0.4 MySQL regexes rely on ICU notation (International Components for Unicode), where word boundaries are expressed as `\b`. In earlier versions, Spencer implementation was used, and boundaries were represented as `[[:<:]]` (before a word) and `[[:>:]]` (after a word).

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
    name,
    '(a|o|e|y|cy|dzy|rzy|owie|i|u|ów|owi|em)\\b',
    ''
) 
FROM `zp_poster`
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gNBefAEq1ajZoeqpV9wQFW/0)**:

```
WITH t AS (
  SELECT 'Józefowi Piłsudski' name
  UNION ALL SELECT 'Piłsudski Józefowi'
)
SELECT 
    name,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(
      name,
      '(a|o|e|y|cy|dzy|rzy|owie|i|u|ów|owi|em)\\b',
      ''
    ) replaced
FROM t;

| name               | replaced       |
| ------------------ | -------------- |
| Józefowi Piłsudski | Józef Piłsudsk |
| Piłsudski Józefowi | Piłsudsk Józef |
```